# Trip Advisor Widget is not working in my site

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

I was trying to embed a trip advisor widget in my website. The code for the Trip Advisor widget is as follows.

```
<div id="TA_selfserveprop546" class="TA_selfserveprop">
<ul id="VvhCFP8xz" class="TA_links JZ5CKDSmc">
<li id="SBEZiTat" class="eyClDs8JVUL">
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/"><img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/150_logo-11900-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script src="https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&amp;uniq=546&amp;locationId=12072630&amp;lang=en_US&amp;rating=true&amp;nreviews=5&amp;writereviewlink=true&amp;popIdx=true&amp;iswide=false&amp;border=true&amp;display_version=2"></script>
```

But it is not  working as it is showing the following error in the chrome console window.

A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://www.tripadvisor.com/WidgetEmbed-selfserveprop?border=true&popIdx=true&iswide=false&locationId=12072630&display_version=2&uniq=546&rating=true&lang=en_US&nreviews=5&writereviewlink=true, is invoked via document.write. This MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.

I have read many forums and tried few option such as async and defer in the script tag.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Cloudflare Rocket Loader? I had a similar issue on a site but I was able to solve it by having Rocket Loader ignore the script:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436-How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-specific-JavaScripts-

I know this question is over 2 years old but I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<script src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/WidgetEmbed-selfserveprop?amp;locationId=12072630&amp;writereviewlink=true&amp;rating=true&amp;border=true&amp;uniq=546&amp;iswide=false&amp;popIdx=true&amp;lang=en_US&amp;nreviews=5&amp;display_version=2" defer></script>
```

instead using jscache